# Flash card app user performance with Google Analytics?

Tags: android, ios, google-analytics, analytics

We are building an app (iOS and Android). The core of the app will be a flash card interface where the user will see a question and then will need to give an appropriate answer. They have a timer and will be shown hints as time goes on.

We want to understand the following on a per question basis (there are potentially 100s of questions):

- Which questions took longer to recall correctly (with and without hints)?
- Which questions had the most errors (with and without hints)?
- Which questions were skipped the most (with and without hints)?
- What were the most common (wrong) answers for a question?

Of course, we are also going to be collecting number of installs, usage, churn, etc., but I figure that is pretty well covered by GA.

Also, we will be storing different information about the user themselves so they can track their progress. This is meant to help us understand how to tweak the flash card data later on so that it is better for the students.

It feels like we could potentially use goals within GA (end goal is to get the right answer), but I am not as familiar with them.

Would this be goals within Google Analytics? Or is Google Analytics not a good use for this type of thing? Is there something else we could use to collect/analyze this information or should we build it ourselves?

Answer (score 2):

Google Analityc suppor [custom variables](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v2/customdimsmets). You can save custom data.
First I would just track every card event as unique pageView (card1234) with it's data.
You can also track events with data for every card.

Goal is more for tracking your app behaviour in general. Example:

**Goal 1**
for tracking wring answers - Make a goal with more that 100 wrong answer (for session or in general for day) - in this way you can track that your app has difficult question

**Gola 2**
Quick answer - Make goal with Event or pageView for card that has small duration (5 second for example). In this way you can check behaviour of whole app.

There are many other good analytics
[Localitic](http://www.localytics.com/plans/)
[KiSSmetric](https://www.kissmetrics.com) payed one
[Mixpanel](https://mixpanel.com/notifications/) - very good for tracking information about users and making segmentation reports
https://mixpanel.com/notifications/
[County](http://count.ly)  -Haven't try this one so can't say anything

[Here](http://www.mobyaffiliates.com/blog/the-best-mobile-site-and-app-analytics-tools/) you can find many others

Comment: How do you feel about the way this information would be displayed in GA? Or would I need to export it and do analysis in R or something else?

Comment: There is way to show them.   
[Here](http://www.sitepoint.com/google-analytics-custom-variables/) you can find tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Im currently using Flurry analytics it, more easy to integrate and simple to use.
http://www.flurry.com/flurry-analytics.html

Comment: Elto, thanks for the quick note. Have you done this type of tracking on a per item level (in the above case it is a question/answer) in your app as well with Flurry?

Comment: @Chris I use Flurry as well and you can track pretty much anything you want.  You just create an event.  Saying that, analyzing the type of data you want to track could be difficult with the interface they provide.

Comment: The interface to do the analysis is important. If it isn't something that can be done in the tool, then is there any reason to not just build something ourselves and use a package like R to do the analysis?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.google.com/analytics/ this is GA official web-page.

**Edit:** Documentation for developers: https://developers.google.com/analytics/

Comment: Do you have a recommendation on how to use GA for this?

Comment: Noo, unfortunately : (